# Type Error occurred when creating object: Peter\Extraemail\Model\Plugin\QuoteManagement\Interceptor

Tags: magento, magento2

I have a custom plugin that plugin using for enter multiple email address from checkout page payment method step this plugin is working file with Magento 2.2.3 but it is not working in Magento 2.3.2 so can anyone help me for resolve this issue thanks

Screenshot link : https://www.screencast.com/t/zFxy3ETG

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code from "Peter\Extraemail\Model\Plugin\QuoteManagement" and any related Dependency Injection (DI) configuration. You can also try to look in "var/log/support_report.log", maybe there is something in there.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the interceptor class not generated properly. I suggest you to do the two things

1. Remove generated folder run the below command from terminal in your magento 2 root directory

```
rm -rf generated/
```

2. For regeneration please run `di:compile` and `cache:flush` commands